# Query first and last name from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I want to query first and last name using custom post type metaboxes.


Code i am using:

```
$name = 'John Doe';

$args = array( 
    'post_type'     => 'customers',
    'post_status'   => array( 'publish', 'pending', 'draft' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'      => 'customer_first_name'
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'           => 'customer_first_name',
            'value'         => $name,
            'compare'       => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'           => 'customer_last_name',
            'value'         => $name,
            'compare'       => 'LIKE',
        ),      
    ),  
);  

$customers = get_posts($args);

$num = count( $customers );
```

If i search only "John" results are showing up. If i search full name "John Doe" there are no results. Why is that?

Comment: You're doing a `LIKE` comparison, which means that both the first _and_ last names need to match `%John Doe%, which isn't going to work because neither field has both names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = 'John Doe';

// Split $name
$name = preg_split( '/\s+/', trim( $name ) );

// Set first name
$first_name = $name[0];

// Last name was provided?
$last_name = isset( $name[1] ) ? $name[1] : null;

// Define meta query args array
$meta_query_args = array();

// Set "first name" meta query or "first name" + "last name" if both exist
if ( is_null( $last_name ) ) {
    $meta_query_args[] = array(
        'key'     => 'customer_first_name',
        'value'   => $first_name,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
} else {
    $meta_query_args[] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // This is default, just trying to be descriptive
        array(
            'key'     => 'customer_first_name',
            'value'   => $first_name,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'customer_last_name',
            'value'   => $last_name,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    );
}

// Set 'meta_query' in your $args variable
$args['meta_query'] = $meta_query_args;
```

Note that you'll have to add extra code to support "last name" + "first name" besides of "first name" + "last name" (order matters).